# Filling in NAs with corresponding row values in another column

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio.
I have a simple data frame that looks like the following:

```
 df <- 
 ID  TAD  TNOM
  1    0    0
  1    0.3  NA
  1    0.6  0.5
  1    1    NA
```

I want a code that fills in the NA for `TNOM` with the corresponding row value in `TAD` column.

The result should be:

```
 df <-
 ID  TAD  TNOM
  1    0    0
  1    0.3  0.3
  1    0.6  0.5
  1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1), TAD=c(0,0.3,0.6,1), TNOM=c(0,NA,0.5,NA))
df
#   ID TAD TNOM
# 1  1 0.0  0.0
# 2  1 0.3   NA
# 3  1 0.6  0.5
# 4  1 1.0   NA
```

Using `ifelse(condition,TRUE,FALSE)`

```
df$TNOM<-ifelse(is.na(df$TNOM),df$TAD,df$TNOM)
```

or using `with(data, expression)`

```
df$TNOM<-with(df,ifelse(is.na(TNOM),TAD,TNOM))
```

or reassigning values based on is.na()

```
df$TNOM[is.na(df$TNOM)] <- df$TAD[is.na(df$TNOM)]
```

all three gives:

```
df
#   ID TAD TNOM
# 1  1 0.0  0.0
# 2  1 0.3  0.3
# 3  1 0.6  0.5
# 4  1 1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Or just assign one over the other - `df$TNOM[is.na(df$TNOM)] <- df$TAD[is.na(df$TNOM)]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select ID, TAD,
      case when TNOM is null then TAD else TNOM end as TNOM 
      from df')
```

Output:

```
  ID TAD TNOM
1  1 0.0  0.0
2  1 0.3  0.3
3  1 0.6  0.5
4  1 1.0  1.0
```